# ExpectedConditions cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, maven

I am waiting for WebElement is clickable using below code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,9);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(CancelListingButton));
```

But I see the error for using `ExpectedConditions` in eclipse as

> ExpectedConditions cannot be resolved to a variable

I am using selenium 3.0 as maven project and included the import statement:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
```

Is there any other dependency to use `ExpectedConditions`?

`pom.xml` dependencies included:

```
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.8.1</version>

    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>

<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
<version>2.0a7</version>
```

Mainly the issue is even after including the import statement:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
```

I still cannot use `ExpectedConditions` anywhere in my code as it gives me error to create a class `ExpectedConditions` and it cannot be resolved to variable.

Comment: You probably have a scope problem. Could you provide more information about this code? I'm suspecting about this CancelListingButton. Maybe you need this.CancelListingButton; but I can't say for sure with only these two lines.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116940/cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable-error-in-eclipse

Comment: Since you included maven as a tag.  It's probably safe to say that theres some contextual information with your maven build.  Can you show us relevant portions of your pom.xml, your dependencies in particular?

Comment: I caught the issue, it was with wrong version for selenium-support dependency. Thanks for leading me this answer

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises from wrong version of `selenium-support`, defined in pom.xml.

Just wanted to point out that `selenium-java` already contains a reference to `selenium-support`, thus no separate dependency declaration is needed for `selenium-support` as the correct version will be used by Maven automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As now a days most of the most of the software testing companies are using Maven for the execution of the selenium frameworks. We need to take care of the dependencies that we are using along with their versions. The issue can be resolved by simply updating the pom file. Instead of using

org.seleniumhq.selenium
selenium-java
3.0.1
org.seleniumhq.selenium
selenium-support
2.0a7

You can update to the pretty latest version.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now right click on your Project. Maven>Update Project issue is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

```
(CancelListingButton));
```

Should be a variable. 
You should make it as:

```
String CancelListingButton = "xpath of your element";
```